# Orthonormal Basis /Linear Combination

Tags: linear-algebra

(a) Find an orthonormal basis {${v_1,v_2,v_3}$} of the image of the linear function given by the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2 \\-1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

(b) Find $a_2$ such that $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2 \\-1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 .$

My attempt

Using Gram-Schmidt I got the part (a) $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\\{-}\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\\{-}\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\\0\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}\frac{2\sqrt 15}{9}\\\frac{\sqrt15}{9}\\\frac{\sqrt15}{9}\\\frac{\sqrt15}{3}\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}{-}\frac{\sqrt267}{81}\\{-}\frac{5\sqrt267}{81}\\\frac{4\sqrt267}{81}\\{-}\frac{15\sqrt267}{81}\end{pmatrix} $$

I'm struggling with part (b) even though I know it's a linear combination my mind is drawing a blank for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the product in part $b$ is a vector, specifically $$\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now we want to find $a_1, a_2, a_3$ such that $$a_1 v_1 + a_2v_2 +a_3v_3 = a_1\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\\{-}\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\\{-}\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\\0 \end{bmatrix} + a_2\begin{bmatrix} \frac{2\sqrt{15}}{9}\\\frac{\sqrt{15}}{9}\\\frac{\sqrt{15}}{9}\\\frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}\end{bmatrix} +a_3\begin{bmatrix} {-}\frac{\sqrt{267}}{81}\\{-}\frac{5\sqrt{267}}{81}\\\frac{4\sqrt{267}}{81}\\{-}\frac{15\sqrt{267}}{81}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

To make our lives easier, le'ts define $w_1=\sqrt{3}v_1, w_2=\sqrt{15}v_2, w_3=\sqrt{267}v_3$. Then define $\displaystyle b_1 =\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{3}}, b_2=\frac{a_2}{\sqrt{15}}, b_3=\frac{a_3}{\sqrt{267}}$. And solve the equivalent system of equations:

$$b_1 w_1 + b_2 w_2 + b_3 w_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

We have four equations (one corresponding to each row of the vector), and three unknowns ($b_1, b_2,$ and $b_3$), so this system of equations is over-determined and should therefore have one or no solutions. However, since by part $a$ you know that $w_1, w_2, w_3$ span the image of the matrix, and that $\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ is in the image of the matrix, it should follow that there exists at least one solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a very nice way to solve this problem. You can take the dot product of $\vec{v_2}$ with $a_1,a_2,a_3$ and the right hand side. Taking advantage of the orthogonality of the vectors you get $$a_1(0)+a_2(1)+a_3(0) = \frac{13\sqrt{15}}{15}$$